# How to check custom equalness for complex objects?

Tags: java, comparison

I have a complex object and want to check only specific properties if they are equal, and if yes the compared objects should be considered equal.

I don't want to override the native `equal()` method as I have a case where I want to leave out some fields during the comparison.

```
public class ComplexObject {
   private ObjectA a;
   //...
   prrivate ObjectN n;
}

public class ObjectA {
   private String name;
   private int age;
}
```

Now for every object I'd require some sort of `Comparator` (just the `java.util.Comparator` is a class used for ordering, not for checking equalness).

```
boolean compare(ObjectA a1, ObjectA a2) {
   return a1.getName().equals(a2.getName()); //age intentionally left out, just showcase
}
```

And then I'd have to chain all "comparators" together and check one after the other, breaking if one comparator returns `false`. So that at the end I can call `boolean ComplexComparator.compare(complexO1, complexO2)` to compare two complex objects, and the comparator chain will then validate all contained member objects.

Probably there is already an appropriate class that provides basic functionallity for these requirement of custom equal comparison (guava, apache, spring)? Or do I have to implement everything myself?

Comment: I don't think having *two definitions for equals()* is a good idea.

Comment: Why can't you use `equals`? I didn't quite get it.

Comment: Call it as you want. You could also name the method `equalForSpecificCase()`, that doesn't change my question...

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I cannot use equals as in general I want to rely on the default `equals()` (eg in hashsets). Only for one single specific case the objects should be considered equal if only a subset of their contained properties are equal (in my example: `ObjectA` only compares the name property, and left out the age).

Comment: On a point of grammar, it's equality, not equalness. This might seem flippant, but actually you may have more success in google searching for equality rather than equalness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since your question is if there are any available libraries to more easily implement a comparison feature to determine equality of two objects...

I know of at least two libraries to do something like that.

By one hand you could use Apache Commons Lang [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (obj == null) { return false; }
   if (obj == this) { return true; }
   if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
     return false;
   }
   MyClass rhs = (MyClass) obj;
   return new EqualsBuilder()
                 .appendSuper(super.equals(obj))
                 .append(field1, rhs.field1)
                 .append(field2, rhs.field2)
                 .append(field3, rhs.field3)
                 .isEquals();
  }
```

Or you could use a Google Guava [ComparisonChain](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html)

```
public int compareTo(Foo that) {
     return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
         .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
         .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
         .result();
   }
```

Comment: I *think* the issue for the OP is that he wants to compare each of his fields using a custom equality check, not `equals`. I believe EqualsBuilder assumes the comparison is using `equals` no?

Comment: Thanks, `ComparisonChain` is great as it can take a `Comparator` as 3rd argument to determine if the objects are equal. So, even a `Comparator` is normally for collection ordering, it seems appropriate here.

Comment: @sprinter How does it assume it?

Comment: when you use `.append(field1, rhs.field1)` then you are instructing it to append the equality check `field1.equals(rhs.field1)`. At least that's my understanding - correct me if I'm mistaken. I had thought that OP wanted a chained series of `field1.customEquals(rhs.field1)`. However he's accepted your answer so I assume I either misunderstood the question or am wrong about EqualsBuilder using `equals`.

Comment: I checked the EqualsBuilder documentation and I believe I'm right: "append(Object lhs, Object rhs)
Test if two Objects are equal using their equals method." So I can't see how it can be used to implement a custom equality check for ComplexObject with custom equality checks for each of the ObjectA...N fields. Though to be honest it was not a well worded question so I might be mistaken about what was being asked.

Comment: @sprinter If some fields in the so-called complex-object must be also custom-compared, I agree this wouldn't work